# Hibernate 4 create sessionfactory in Abstract Factory

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, jboss

I'm working in a web app with Hibernate 4.2, I have the Abstract Factory Pattern implemented but for create the session factory I have not a init method because I use the first call to create the session factory to reuse in forward like a static, like you can see I get the session from the DAOImpl, to work and finally I close it. First I want to ask if this practice it's correct? Is there another better practice?

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HibernateSessionFactory.class);

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ServiceRegistry sr = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);

            return sf;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed.", ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw  ex;

        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdownSessionFactory() {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

}
```

**DAOIMPL**

```
public class RecordDAOImpl implements RecordDAO{.....

public String getRecord (Long id){
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();


        try {
            session.beginTransaction();     
            .
            .
            .

            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return value;
    }
```

**DAO**

```
    public interface FieldDAO {.....

String getRecord (Long id);
```

**Factory**

```
public class HibernateFactoryDao extends DAOFactory {...

@Override
    public RecordDAOImpl getRecordDAO() {
        return new RecordDAOImpl();
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought on using CDI in order to inject your factory in your `RecordDAOImpl` and retrieve your session according to your database type?

Comment: aribeiro, this a good advice, I was trying to find a good example with Hibernate 4, Do you know a good example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could use CDI in order to inject your factory into your `RecordDAOImpl` and retrieve your session according to your ORM type.

As a possible example, you could try the following:

**1.** Create a qualifier to needle between your ORM factories

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public @interface ORMSessionFactory {

    ORMType value();

    public enum ORMType {
        HIBERNATE,
        ECLIPSELINK;
    }
}
```

**2.** Define an interface for your session factory

```
public interface MySessionFactory {

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory();

    public void shutdownSessionFactory();
}
```

**3.** If necessary, create an abstract class that holds the common behavior across all ORM factory implementations

```
public abstract class AbstractSessionFactory implements MySessionFactory {

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AbstractSessionFactory() {
        buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }

    protected abstract SessionFactory buildSessionFactory();
}
```

**4.** Annotate your ORM factory implementations with the respective type

```
@ORMSessionFactory(ORMType.HIBERNATE)
public class HibernateSessionFactory extends AbstractSessionFactory {

    @Override
    protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);

            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

**5.** Then, on your `RecordDAOImpl` you could do the following

```
public class RecordDAOImpl implements RecordDAO {

    @Inject
    @ORMSessionFactory(ORMType.HIBERNATE)
    private MySessionFactory mySessionFactory;

    @Override
    public String getRecord(Long id) {
        String value = null;
        Session session = mySessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            // do some transactional stuff

            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Don't forget that, in order to enable CDI, you should have a *beans.xml* inside your *META-INF* (JAR) or *WEB-INF* folder (WAR):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```